# What's the behavior of the og:url with a google analytics campaign ?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-opengraph

I'm working to implement Open Graph protocole on ours websites.
If I refer to the Open Graph documentation, I should put these kind of input for the og:url value :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/section/article.html" />
```

If I proceed like this, I should be able to :
- access stats from the facebook insight for a specific url + for the all website.

But I want more ! Indeed I want to be able to :
- See these data on google analytics (not only in Facebook)
- Have another level of analytics based on section
- See what traffic coming from "like button" vs copy/past

To do this, I was thinking to have something like this :

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.website.com/section/article.html?utm_source=section&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=social" />
```

So here are my questions :
- Is it allowed, recommanded, gonna worked ?
- If I do so, could I be sure to not have duplicate item on the FB analytics (http://www.website.com/section/article.html vs website.com/section/article.html?utm_source=section&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=social)
- Is there another solution ? (linking to facebook.website.com/section/article.html with an analytics code redirecting to website.com/section/article.html ?)

Thank's a lot
Sorry for my poor english syntax (a french guy)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking too many questions at once. I'm going to break it down.

**access stats from the facebook insight for a specific url + for the all website.** Wrong! The Open Graph protocol is designed to give Facebook and other websites semantic information of the type of content on your website, and what it is. That's where the default information populated when sharing links on Facebook is taken from. [Read the manual again.](http://ogp.me/) If you want Insights, [go to this page.](http://facebook.com/insights)

**See these data on google analytics** Only a fool would believe that Facebook would allow Insights to be exported to Google Analytics. Google Analytics and Facebook Insights are not interchangable. If you want to track your webpages, use the former, to track your Facebook Page, use the latter.

**Have another level of analytics based on section** Facebook doesn't provide services to track how long and how much users are on each tab.

**See what traffic coming from "like button" vs copy/past** Facebook Insights. Works for me!

**If I do so, could I be sure to not have duplicate item on the FB analytics** Query strings are treat as separate pages as the same page without a query string. For my website `?id=32` and `?id=92` are treat as different pages. That was for my online streaming radio site. Each query string showed a different song. *You can sort the query string problem out yourself.*

**Update!** [Canonical url's can solve that problem.](http://davidwalsh.name/canonical-link-rel)

If you had phrased your question in an understandable way, you would have your question answered by now; instead of having to ask me on Twitter to answer it.

The End!